# Centre grid item in rest of available space in container (MUI React)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, vite

I am a newbie with MUI and styling HTML components and I have a question.
I am using `Grid` in my `React` project. I want to create something like this (it is edited in Paint, and it can be not aligned properly):
[image]

In this case, the second element in the bottom `Grid` container is aligned and is exactly centred between the 2 components above.

But in my project, it looks like this:
[image]

I don't have any idea, how can I make it like in the first picture.
This is my App component code:

```
function App() {
    return (
    <Box sx={{ px: 5, py: 5 }}>
        <Grid container columnSpacing={5}>
            <Grid item xs={3}>
                <Paper elevation={10}>
                    <Typography>My text</Typography>
                </Paper>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={3}>
                <Paper elevation={10}>
                    <Typography>My text</Typography>
                </Paper>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={3}>
                <Paper elevation={10}>
                    <Typography>My text</Typography>
                </Paper>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={3}>
                <Paper elevation={10}>
                    <Typography>My text</Typography>
                </Paper>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>

        <Grid container columnSpacing={5} sx={{ mt: 5 }}>
            <Grid item xs={6}>
                <Paper elevation={10}>
                    <Typography>My text</Typography>
                </Paper>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={4}>
                <Paper elevation={10}>
                    <Typography>My text</Typography>
                </Paper>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Box>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
      <Grid container columnSpacing={5} sx={{ mt: 5 }}>
        <Grid item xs={6}>
          <Paper elevation={10}>
            <Typography>My text</Typography>
          </Paper>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={1}></Grid>
        <Grid item xs={4}>
          <Paper elevation={10}>
            <Typography>My text</Typography>
          </Paper>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={1}></Grid>
      </Grid>
```